# Can there be more than 2 zeta zeros between a Gram point and a Franca-Leclair point?

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta

The $n$-th Gram point can be approximated with the formula:

$$\frac{2 \pi  \left(n-\frac{7}{8}\right)}{W\left(\frac{n-\frac{7}{8}}{\exp (1)}\right)}$$

and the $n$-th Franca-Leclair point can be approximated with the formula:

$$\frac{2 \pi  \left(n-\frac{11}{8}\right)}{W\left(\frac{n-\frac{11}{8}}{\exp (1)}\right)}$$

where $W$ is the Lambert-W function.

Gram points are points $t$ such that:

$$\Re\left(\zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) \neq 0$$
and 
$$\Im\left(\zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) = 0$$

Franca-Leclair points are points $t$ such that:

$$\Re\left(\zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) = 0$$
and 
$$\Im\left(\zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) \neq 0$$

where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

The maximum number of zeros in between a Gram point and Franca Leclair point appears to be 2, and as an example I use this plot of the real and imaginary part of the Riemann zeta function which shows 2 consecutive zeta zeros with no Gram point or Franca-Leclair point in between them. It is also an example of the Lehmer's phenomenon:

[image: Lehmers phenomenon]

Mathematica code for the plot:

```
Show[Plot[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I*t]], {t, 17143.8 - 1/20, 17143.8 + 1/20}, 
  PlotRange -> {-0.005, 0.005}],
 Plot[Im[Zeta[1/2 + I*t]], {t, 17143.8 - 1/20, 17143.8 + 1/20}, 
  PlotRange -> {-0.005, 0.005}]]
```

My question is:

> Can there be more than 2 zeta zeros in between a Gram
>   point and a Franca-Leclair point?

Comment: Can you explain all the formulas and ideas you mentioned ? And you should plot $\xi(1/2+it)$ together with the real and imaginary part of $\zeta(1/2+it)$

Comment: You can find more information here:
Gram points:
https://oeis.org/A002505
Franca-Leclair points:
https://oeis.org/A273061

Comment: I'm asking if you can explain rigorously what you are talking about.